# How to pull findbugs or checkstyle coding rules from source repository in Sonar?

Tags: checkstyle, findbugs, pmd, sonarqube

I understand we can [upload code rules](http://www.sonarqube.org/screencasts2/configuring-coding-rules/) in Solar admin dashboard. But is there a way to have these rules(Checkstyle, Findbugs & PMD config xmls) in the source repository which Sonar will use after every build?

Thanks

Comment: If you're using SonarQube, what's the need of being able to pull them from a source repository?

Comment: In our case Dev+QA maintain code & SCM team owns SonarQube.  Idea is Dev maintaining code, QA team managing code coverage/formatting rules and SCM manage SonarQube. We would like to reduce the dependency between SCM & Dev teams.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible at this time. At the time of this writing, SonarQube must be the master (i.e. leading) system for rules definitions. So you define the rules once in SonarQube, then use them whereever you need.

In theory, you could write a script that checks for differences between a rule definition from the source repository and from SonarQube. If a difference is found, you could upload a modified profile to SonarQube via the web interface. I would advise against such a mechanism, because it would be hard to build in a reliable way and counteracts the basic idea of SonarQube as the leading source of quality information.

If you are using Eclipse, for example, you can specify the Checkstyle rules as a *remote configuration* pointing directly to the permalink URL in SonarQube. This way, your local configuration is automatically in sync with SonarQube.